# To correctly express a property of something

Tags: articles, plural-forms

I made several sentences related to the usage of the preposition `of` and articles. Please confirm if these are natural or at least correct:

**Articles**

1. Color is ([empty] / a / the) property of matter.
   It seems `a` is correct because color is not the only property of matter. Can we omit an article?
2. Color is one of the properties of matter. (this is too verbose, though)

**To express property of a collection of things**

1. The colors of the cups are all different.
2. The colors of each cup are all different.
3. The color of each cup is different from the other.

In the list, 1. seems a bit ambiguous because it is possible to interpret that we have multiple cups, and each cup has various colors. `the colors` lead me to think that the colors of each one of the cups are different. In other words, 1. can be interpreted to mean either 2. or 3.

**Using `respectively`**

1. The indices of A (or / and) B are 1 and 2, respectively.
   It seems `and` is natural.
2. The mothers of Davis and Taylor are Mrs. Davis and Taylor, respectively.
   This is one of the most confusing sentences for me, which is similar to '*the colors of the cups*'. Can we say `mothers` when Davis and Taylor can have only one mother?

Comment: There are lots of questions on different topics here.  Could you edit it down to one, or would you let me edit?

Comment: @JamesK Thank you, but I don't figure out how to make the connected topics more concise.

Comment: (Articles) Yes, _a_ is correct, and we can't omit the article. (2) is perfectly acceptable.,

Comment: It would take an unusual context for #2 *The colors of each cup are all different* to be "correct". That version implies that each cup has *multiple* colours that are unique across the entire collection (i.e. - none of the colours on any given cup also occur on any *other* cup). ***Or*** that each individual coloured area on each cup is a different shade to every other coloured area on that specific cup, perhaps.

Comment: (Properties) More than one description would be needed. For example, **Each multi-colored cup is unique**.